# Hive RegexSerDe not giving the correct output

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, bigdata

I am having input text file having data as

0000856214AB25    256 T PL1423AS

2563458547CD12   748 S  AK2523YU

Used below Regex query to get the output

```
hive> CREATE TABLE test_regex(
>f1 STRING,f2 STRING,
>f3 STRING,f4 STRING,
>f5 STRING,f6 STRING,
>f7 STRING) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe' 
>WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("input.regex" = 
>"([0-9]{10})([A-Z]{2})([0-9]{2})\\s+([0-9]{3})\\s+([A-Z]{1})\\s+([A-Z]{2})([A-Z0-9]{6})",
>"output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s %5s %6s %7s")
>STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

OutPut:

```
hive> select *from test_regex;

0000856214  AB  25  256 T   PL  1423AS

2563458547  CD  12  748 S   AK  2523YU
```

but when I am trying to get ouput using below query

```
Query: Select f1 from test_regex;
or     Select f1,f3,f5 from test_regex;
```

Output: Error

FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask

`
.
.
Can someone help me to reslove the above issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the complete error message.

Comment: posting whole error in 3 parts.

<1>

Total MapReduce jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Starting Job = job_201410131439_0291, Tracking URL = http://masterhost.localdomain:50030/jobdetail
s.jsp?jobid=job_201410131439_0291
Kill Command = /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_201410131439_0291
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers:0
2014-12-01 19:25:08,109 Stage-1 map =0%,  reduce = 0%
2014-12-01 19:26:01,107 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%
Ended Job = job_201410131439_0291 with error

Comment: <2>
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
Job Tracking URL: http://masterhost.localdomain:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201410131439_0291
Examining task ID: task_201410131439_0291_m_000002 (and more) from job job_201410131439_0291

Task with the most failures(4):
-----
Task ID:
  task_201410131439_0291_m_000000

URL:
  http://localhost:50030/taskdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201410131439_0291&tipid=task_201410131439_0291_m_000000

-----
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf

Comment: <3>
(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:413)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:332)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)

Comment: <4>
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.ja

FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched:
Job 0: Map: 1   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec

Can you check and help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not the real error, here's how to find it:
Go to the hadoop jobtracker web-dashboard, find the hive mapreduce jobs that failed and look at the logs of the failed tasks. That will show you the real error.

or 
in tmp/user/hive.log and see the log

caused by org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe not found

go to http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhivecontrib081jar.htm

```
download jar hive-contrib-0.8.1.jar
```

then in hive,add the jar according to your system path

```
 ADD JAR /home/user17/hive/hive-contrib-0.8.1.jar

select f1 from test_regex;
```

output

```
0000856214
2563458547
```

Comment: I can see hive-contrib jar file under "/usr/lib/hive/lib" path.

is this the right path am looking to??

what should i do next??

Comment: then execute this command on hive terminal. ADD JAR /usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-contrib-0.8.1.jar

Comment: Hi @Kishore 
how can I add 25  and 12 after getting result as below using the above mentioned query?

0000856214  AB  25  256 T   PL  1423AS

2563458547  CD  12  748 S   AK  2523YU

Thanks, Palash

Comment: I am not getting your query, you want to make into single line or want to add 25 and 12?

Comment: I want to add 25 and 12 as in thw mentioned above query it is defined as String. so do we need to convert it or we can do it directly ?

Comment: select sum(cast(f3 as int)) from test_regex;

Comment: **select sum(CAST(BAL_AM AS INT)) from ABC where P_ID = 'CU';**

I tried this but it is throwing error.

java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object

Comment: PFB result for the query
              00
              00
              00
              00
              00
              00
              00
          735523
              00
              00
              00
              00
              00
              00
              00
              00
           54402
              00
          339809
              00

Comment: select sum(CAST(BAL_AM AS BIGINT)) from ABC, if it will not work then check there may be different problem with your data or you have to make UDF.

Comment: tried this but now working..

2015-02-25 16:05:21,179 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 4.03 sec
its still running with reduce=0%

 is it because of spaces?? like if it is 735523 then fine and if it is 00 so in data actually it is "    00".
can you suggest what might be the issue?
or
can you please help to make UDF?

Comment: select sum(CAST(TRIM(BAL_AM) AS BIGINT)) from ABC

Comment: Thanks Kishore,
after so much of try. it is working without "CAST". i can see sum of the required fields without converting it to INT/BIGINT.
Thanks again for you help.

will get back to you if i get stuck somewhere.
thanks again

Comment: can you show the query so I will learn, how it done without cast if field is in string format

Comment: PFB query 

select sum(BAL_AM) from abc where trim(P_ID) ='6U';

I am getting sum of the amounts as expected